# Inherit ArrayList to child class

Tags: java

I would like to inherrit the `rooms` variable just as `foo` is being inherited. I have searched around google and stackoverflow but couldn't find relevant posts. It may be a short description of the question but I don't think anything more is needed.

#### Code

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HomeAbstraction { // HomeAbstraction = Rooms; It's named like this to fit the rest of the project
    float area;

    public HomeAbstraction(float area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
}

class Home {
    String foo = "bar";
    ArrayList < HomeAbstraction > rooms = new ArrayList < HomeAbstraction > ();

    // setter
    public void setRooms(HomeAbstraction rooms) {
        this.rooms.add(rooms);
    }
}

class Department extends Home {
    // constructor
    public Department() {
        foo = "foo"; // works fine
        rooms; // should be pulled from parent but isn't working
        rooms.setRooms(new HomeAbstraction(50)); // Not sure if I can access the setter from this child class
    }
}
```

#### Error log

---

```
idk.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        rooms.setRooms(new HomeAbstraction(50));
             ^
  symbol:   method setRooms(HomeAbstraction)
  location: variable rooms of type ArrayList<HomeAbstraction>
1 error
```

Comment: "should be pulled from parent but isn't working" - "isn't working" doesn't tell us anything about the way in which it's not working. Personally I'd suggest you keep fields private, but that's a different matter. Without knowing in what way the current code "isn't working" we can't help you.

Comment: (Note that a statement of `rooms;` on its own isn't valid, but that's got nothing to do with inheritance. I'd also suggest that a method called `setRooms` which actually adds a room to an existing list is very confusingly named...)

Comment: By isn't working I mean it can't be accessed by the child class.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. Please post the *exact* error message, in the question. I suspect it's the `setRooms` method call that isn't working, because `ArrayList<HomeAbstraction>` doesn't have a method called `setRooms`. Perhaps instead of `rooms.setRooms(...)` you actually just meant `setRooms(...)`?

Comment: I've just tried compiling your code, and removing the invalid statement `rooms;` (which as I say has *nothing* to do with inheritance) it provides the error message I'd expect: error: cannot find symbol; method `setRooms(HomeAbstraction);` variable rooms of type `ArrayList<HomeAbstraction>`". So it's resolving `rooms` just fine - but as I said before, `ArrayList<HomeAbstraction>` doesn't have a `setRooms` method.

Comment: Sure, in a moment. I got an error message by deleting `rooms;` as you said that hints me something. I will update the question.

Comment: I couldn't see the real error because I accidentaly hide it when testing with the `rooms;` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
rooms.add(new HomeAbstraction(50));
```

or

```
super.setRooms(new HomeAbstraction(50));
```

or

```
super.rooms.add(new HomeAbstraction(50));
```